# matplotlib, dateutil, and numpy are not working for me

Tags: python, numpy, import, matplotlib, python-dateutil

When I use pip freeze, it shows that i have `matplotlib==1.4.x`, `python-dateutil==1.5`, and `numpy==1.9.0.dev-54d3559`, but in python when i try `import matplotlib`, it says that it requires `dateutil`

Also, when i try `import dateutil` or `import numpy` it says the modules not found.

I don't really know how what is going wrong here. I've tried all the solutions I've found online and none have worked for me.

Comment: Check to make sure you're in your virtual environment,  with it activated ( source venv/bin/activate)  when  your running  the imports.  It sounds like your running pip freeze out of the virtual environment and it's picking up on the local installed libraries. Try running pip freeze again once your sure your on the virtual environment and check if numpy ect is installed there.

Comment: Make sure you are using the same python version of your matplotlib and numpy!